# I have no image on my Canon PowerShot Pro1 camera

Tags: shutter

I have no images on my Canon PowerShot Pro1. When I press the shutter nothing happens. The monitor and viewfinder displays the info.

Comment: Did you put CF card in camera? Did you set camera in Play mode to check the images?

Comment: yes card is in. can't shoot any images. shutter not responding.

Comment: In which mode you set your camera?

Comment: the shutter doesn't work in any mode.

Comment: Have you try to charge the batter and test again?

Comment: Yes several times.

Comment: For me it seems like problem which need service. But even if you find someone to repair it maybe will be cheaper to buy new camera.

Comment: Yes, Canon says the camera is too old to repair. Too bad it's a great camera.